# Split up XML in Groovy

Tags: xml, xslt, groovy

I have an XML that looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<header>
<row>
 <item1>stuff</item1>
 <item2>stuff</item2>
</row>
<row>
 <item1>stuff</item1>
 <item2>stuff</item2>
</row>
...
</header>
```

I want to read this in

```
def doc = new XmlSlurper().parseText(message)
```

And then output each "row" element as an individual message. For instance:

```
<header>
<row1>
     <item1>stuff</item1>
     <item2>stuff</item2>
</row1>
</header>
```

What is the correct way to do this in Groovy? Should I use an XSLT or is that overcomplicating things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your case is really this simple, I'd go with Groovy which really shines in such scenarios.

```
final xml = '''
    <header>
        <row>
            <item1>stuff11</item1>
            <item2>stuff12</item2>
        </row>
        <row>
            <item1>stuff21</item1>
            <item2>stuff22</item2>
        </row>
    </header>
'''

final xmlDoc = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
```

Having read a document, construct a document for each row

```
def rowId = 1

String singleRow = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    header {
        "row$rowId" {
            mkp.yield xmlDoc.row[rowId-1].children()
        }
    }
}
```

And it's done.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. That looks very straightforward, but two issues. The first is, each row doesn't have an ID, or anything to differentiate it from other rows besides the data inside. The second is, what is mkp.yield?

Comment: @Steve I tried to follow your example, given input and output. Provide an actual example and I'll try to adjust the code. `mkp` is a special namespace used to escape away from the normal building mode, [as explained](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/xml/StreamingMarkupBuilder.html)